# British as an adjective

Tags: adjectives, synonyms

Can you say: **British residents=UK residents**

1.Are these two synonymous with each other?

2.Is ''UK'' also a formal adjective here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1**

British and UK are not quite the same thing. The full name of the UK is *United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Island*, so these two terms have slightly different meanings since "British residents" doesn't necessarily include Northern Ireland.

However in casual use people don't always pay attention to this distinction, so some people will use the terms interchangeably.

**2**

In the noun phrase "UK residents", UK is a **noun adjunct**, not an adjective. It is not grammatically correct to say "Fred is UK", because UK is not an adjective. It is grammatical to say "Fred is British".

Comment: Hello there, thx for the answer. I'd like to know if your a native or something since you didn't add this up to your profile. UK residents cannot be used? But I've seen it in many different references... hmm I need this term to be valid if that's possible for my write-ups as synonyms... :( pls. shed more light.

Comment: Hello John. I am a native speaker from London. It's fine and correct to use "UK residents". I just said that we don't classify the word UK as an adjective - its a noun.

Answer (score 1):

Generally if you say

> I am a UK passport holder.
>   I am a British passport holder.

It will be understood to mean you have that little red booklet (for now).

If you say

> I am a British resident.
>   I am a UK resident.

It means you live somewhere covered by the jurisdiction of the passport: England, Scotland, Wales, Northern Ireland.

Saying "***I'm a British resident***" usually refers to *England* since it is the majority population and otherwise one would say

> I live in Scotland.
>   I live in Wales.
>   I live in Northern Ireland.

for reasons of local pride and feelings towards the English.

You can also say

> I'm a **Brit**

but not

> I'm a **UK**

you will need to say

> I'm *from* the UK.

Comment: I have edited some punctuations and other stuffs. Kindly check if I clearly understood the context of your answer based on my edits. Thx for the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a really complicated area because residence, domicile, and nationality have distinct technical meanings, and also because the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland is both a legal concept and a geographical expression.

So I could be a British resident without having a British domicile or without having British nationality. I could even have a British domicile without being a British resident.

As to geography, "Great Britain" is the name of an island comprising three nations: England, Wales and Scotland. "Northern Ireland" is a part of the island of Ireland which is also part of the United Kingdom.

If you are speaking of residence, then that is administered for the whole of the UK in the same way. So **in that context** British resident is a synonym of UK resident. But that emphatically does not mean that British and UK are synonyms more widely. It all depends on the precise terms in question.

Comment: My question is if 'UK resident' is synonymous with 'UK resident', I didn't know the term 'noun adjunct' before so ('UK' in 'UK resident') has already been answered by bdsl, which is what I needed. Thx for the answer anyway.

Comment: As for the UK as a noun, UK=england, scotland and wales.(synonyms, a native had said that to us) but I'd like to clarify coz your answer here is Great Britain=england, scotland and wales right? Now I'm confused.

Comment: Yes GB= England + Scotland + Wales. UK = GB + Northern Ireland